# Is it possible to save the module as a library to avoid its permanent copy and past in each program code

Tags: module, fortran

I've written a module that includes all the necessary subroutines and functions I need. This module is a general one and I wonder if there is any way to avoid permanent use of the full-code version of the module and instead call it as a Fortran library or internal saved module?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module the following way. If you build the code of a module, for this example the module is called capsule and has a subroutine called sub, the file "capsule.mod" is generated. You can now use this module in another project the following way:

1. Add capsule.mod to the list of files the linker should use, or if you use an ide, simply copy the file into the folder, where all the objectcode files are.
2. Use the command

   ```
   use capsule
   ```

   in the subroutine, function or main program you want to use the module's subroutine.
3. Call the Subroutine

   ```
   call sub()
   ```

And you done reusing your once build file capsule.mod.

Edit: I meant the compiler, the module have to be visible to the compiler and not to the linker.

Comment: A linker typically knows nothing about .mod files produced by some Fortran compiler.  Linkers work with object code.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you may want to compile your generic routine as a shared library or DLL. The post [Shared library in Fortran, minimal example does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112185/shared-library-in-fortran-minimal-example-does-not-work) has a minimal example for gfortran and unix-y systems; an example for Intel Fortran on Windows is at https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/535308. I've seen rumors that gfortran can produce DLLs on Windows using the `-shared` flag but I'd be very careful going that route.

Comment: As Alex mentioned... Use USE and then you get some checking of the interface.

Comment: Agreed; it wasn't clear if the goal was to link to a precompiled module or to a shared library. A downside of modules is that `.mod` files aren't portable across compilers (i.e. one built with ifort won't work with code built with gfrotran). Shared libraries (`.so`, `.dll`) should avoid that problem at the cost of no interface checking and additional complexity in compilation. Tradeoffs...